# How to use a translated taxonomy in autocomplete term-reference fields?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

When I translate a taxonomy to other languages, I cannot use it in autocomplete term-reference fields.

The auto complete field will show items only in the default language; if I try to fill the form from another language, nothing shows up in the field when I type.

It happens only when I use the autocomplete widget.

I am using Drupal 7.15.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using 'Entity Translation' or the core 'Content translation'?

I think the sub-module **Multilingual select** (from [**Internationalization**](http://drupal.org/project/i18n)) should handle this for 'Content translation' (didn't test it, though).

But for Entity Translation, this doesn't seem to work (yet): see [Entity translation and the Multilingual select i18n submodule interactions](http://drupal.org/node/1727578) and [Language aware edit form and autocomplete](http://drupal.org/node/1506054).

Answer (score 1):

read this  "[Localize terms show always the default language](http://drupal.org/node/1070256)" . but I personally suggest you don't translate terms, you can add both terms in you vocab . terms_data table impproved  in Drupal7 and  handle very much terms charmly.